# Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property

Tags: java, spring, jsp, file-handling

I am saving an image file from jsp and renaming it in the controller

The problem is that same piece of code is working in one part of the controller and not working in another part of the controller

here is the jsp code which is same in both cases:-

```
<div class="form-group ">
                                <label for="photo">Photo:</label>
                                <form:input type="file" class="filestyle" path="studentPhoto"
                                    id="studentPhoto" placeholder="Upload Photo"
                                    required="required" />
                            </div>
```

Here is the part of the controller where it is working as expected:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student", params = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAddStudent(@ModelAttribute @Valid Student student,
            BindingResult result, Model model) throws IOException {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.getAllErrors().toString());

            model.addAttribute("examination_names", ExaminationName.values());

            ArrayList<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
            roles.add(Role.STUDENT);
            model.addAttribute("roles", roles);

            return "student/add";
        } else {

            System.out.println("Inside postAddStudent");
            System.out.println(student);
            student = studentService.save(student);

            String PROFILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION = servletContext.getRealPath("/")
                    + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator
                    + "student_images" + File.separator;

            BufferedImage photo = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(student
                    .getStudentPhoto().getBytes()));
            File destination = new File(PROFILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION
                    + student.getId() + "_photo" + ".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(photo, "jpg", destination);

            return "redirect:student?id=" + student.getId();

        }

    }
```

Below is the part of controller where it is not working and says error:-

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile for property studentPhoto; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile] for property studentPhoto: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

ControllerCode

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/examForm", params = "edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postEditExamForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid Student student,
        BindingResult result, Model model) throws IOException {

    String PROFILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION = servletContext.getRealPath("/")
            + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator
            + "student_images" + File.separator;

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("flags", Flag.values());
        return "examForm/edit";

    } else {

        Student updatedStudent = studentService.findOne(student.getId());

        updatedStudent.setDisqualifiedDescription(student
                .getDisqualifiedDescription());
        student = studentService.update(updatedStudent);


        BufferedImage photo = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(student
                .getStudentPhoto().getBytes()));
        File destination = new File(PROFILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION
                + student.getId() + "_photo" + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(photo, "jpg", destination);


        return "redirect:examForm?id=" + updatedStudent.getId();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using the same Form for both the controllers? if not then paste both jsp form.

Comment: No they are in different form ..I tried in one and it was working there then I moved it to another where it is not working

Comment: Paste the one which is not working too.

Comment: I have came across some articles relating to that, but not working here is one http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-failed-to-convert-property-value-in-file-upload-form/

Comment: I have pasted two controller code first one is working fine second is not working

Comment: Problem seems to be in your Jsp form. Paste both the jsp forms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107483/discussion-between-md-faisal-and-sanjay-rawat).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You were missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form:form...>` tag.

Since your form doesn't had `enctype="multipart/form-data"` spring was taking `<form:input type="file"..` as `String` and throwing error when it cannot convert `String` to `MultipartFile` for `studentPhoto` of type `MultipartFile` in `Student` class.

Here's the complete [source code](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/JamiaNew).